Unreachable Python and Go code after trying to free C.CString from Python
I am testing around with writing a C library for my Go Program, so that my Python scripts can call them. I was able to get it to work by following guides and documentation, but I am concerned that I am not properly freeing memory returned with C.CString from Go, as the code after using C.free(unsafe.Pointer(result)) seems to be unreachable on both Python and Go end of things. Trying to debug with Python, it stops when trying to get past the free function.
Setup on Go with added logging in the Free func:

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime/debug"
    "sync/atomic"
    "unsafe"
)

// #include <stdbool.h>
// #include <stdint.h>
// #include <stdio.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"

var allocCount int32

//export Test
func Test(s *C.char) *C.char {
    goS := C.GoString(s)
    res := goS + "!"
    fmt.Println(res)
    atomic.AddInt32(&allocCount, 1)
    return C.CString(res)
}

//export FreeResult
func FreeResult(result *C.char) C.bool {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Recovered in FreeResult: %v\n", r)
            fmt.Printf("Stack trace:\n%s\n", debug.Stack())
        }
    }()

    fmt.Printf("Entered FreeResult\n")
    fmt.Printf("Result: %v\n", result) // Print address of result
    fmt.Printf("Allocated memory before freeing: %d\n", atomic.LoadInt32(&allocCount))

    if result != nil {
        C.free(unsafe.Pointer(result))
        atomic.AddInt32(&allocCount, -1)
        fmt.Println("Freed result")
        fmt.Println("Allocated memory after freeing: ", atomic.LoadInt32(&allocCount))
        return C.bool(true)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Error: result is nil")
        return C.bool(false)
    }
}

//export GetAllocCount
func GetAllocCount() C.int {
    return C.int(atomic.LoadInt32(&allocCount))
}

func main() {}

On Python:
import ctypes

library = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./lib.dll')

test = library.Test
test.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
test.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

free_result = library.FreeResult
free_result.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
free_result.restype = ctypes.c_bool

get_alloc_count = library.GetAllocCount
get_alloc_count.argtypes = []
get_alloc_count.restype = ctypes.c_int



res = test(b"Hello")
print(res)
print(get_alloc_count())
res = free_result(res)
print(res)
print(get_alloc_count())

Command line output looks like
Hello!
Result from test: b'Hello!'
Alloc count after test: 1
Pointer value before freeing: b'Hello!'
Entered FreeResult
Result: 0x1e52441b950
Allocated memory before freeing: 1

I am on windows, so I build with
go build -buildmode=c-shared -o lib.dll lib.go


Defining the return type as
test.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)

Fixed the problem. Apparently Python does special handling with c_char_p and returns a copy of bytes, and I lost my pointer entirely.
